# Plotting global sea surface temperatures on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, grib

I am trying to plot global sea surface temperatures for April 2015 on MATLAB using [JMA's dataset in GRiB format](http://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/elnino/cobesst/cobe-sst.html). I have also installed the nctoolbox and m_map toolboxes.

Below is my code:

```
!wget http://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/elnino/cobesst/gpvdata/2010-2019/sst201504.grb
nc=ncgeodataset('sst201504.grb')
nc.variables %to check the variable names in this file
lat=double('lat');
lon=double('lon');
sst=double(squeeze('Water_temperature_depth_below_sea'));
m_proj('miller','lat',[min(lat(:)) max(lat(:))],...'lon',[min(lon(:)) max(lon(:))])
m_pcolor(lon,lat,sst);
```

However, when I used the m-pcolor function, the following error message is generated:

```
Error using pcolor (line 53)
Color data input must be a matrix.

Error in m_pcolor (line 53)
[h]=pcolor(X,Y,data,varargin{:});
```

I am still able to plot the coastline and gridlines using the following code though, but without the coloured temperature anomalies:

```
m_coast;
m_grid;
```

Did I miss out anything in my code? `lat` and `lon` are **1x3** double arrays, while `sst` is a **1x33** double array.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21996-how-to-use-m_pcolor-and-or-pcolorm

Comment: Thanks for the link @NKN. I am suspecting that the problem lies with declaring and defining the variable 'sst'. However, I have no idea how could I correct the error.

Comment: check the type and size of the `sst` variable and add it to the question.

Comment: @NKN I added the properties of sst into the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in improperly defining the variables and array sizes, as the array sizes of `lat`, `lon` and `sst` do not match each other correctly. It has to do with the file problem though, as evident from the fact that the array sizes for `lat` and `lon` are too small to display gridded global SST data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve all your difficulties, but double('lat') is converting the *string* "lat" to a double. It will always be [108 97 116]. Remove the quotes like so: double(lat).

Similarly for double(squeeze('Water_temperature_depth_below_sea')). You want to convert the variable to double, not the variable's *name*.